# Prime factorization of a big number

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes, prime-factoring

I'm trying to create a program for prime factorization of a number and this is the code I came up with.

```
def primeFactors(n):
    l=[]
    ss=0
    for i in range(2,n,1):
    #checking for prime
        t=0
        for j in range(2,i):
            if(i==2):
                continue
            if(i%j==0):
                t=t+1   
        if(t>0):
            continue
        else:
            if(n==0):
                break
            else:
                print(i)
                if(n%i==0):
                    n=n//i
                    ss=ss+1
                    i=i-1
                if(n%i!=0 and ss>0):
                    l.append(i)
                    l.append(ss)
                    ss=0
                else:
                    continue
    q=""
    for i in range(0,len(l),2):
        q=q+"("+str(l[i])+"**"+str(l[i+1])+")"
    return q
```

The working of the code is as follows:

1. It checks whether the number in the outer loop is a prime or not.
2. If it is a prime, then it proceeds to check whether division of the number with `n` would yield a remainder of 0 or not, if it does, divide it.
3. Increment `ss` which is the number of times the prime number would be used in the whole factorisation. Also, decrement the value of `i` so that when it increments at the end of the loop, it remains the same to check again whether `i` can divide `n` or not.
4. If it cannot divide and `ss` (number of times `i` could divide) is more than 0 then we append it to a list.

I am getting timeout errors in this and cannot figure out how to go about fixing it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This can be possibly caused because you check all the divisors up to `n`. It is sufficient to check up to square root of `n`.

Comment: I'll try it out

Comment: It works but the output is completely off
For (4 * * 3)(10 * *2)(16 * * 1) should equal '(2 * *2)(3 * *3)(5)(7)(11 * * 2)(17)

Comment: Is there any way to prevent increments through some other way so that I can check divisibility by that same prime factor again

Comment: my code runs but it still increments value of i, its not checking the divisibility again with the same even with the ```i-1``` line

Comment: use `while` loop instead of a `for` loop increment *i* only when *n%i* is not equal 0. else keep on dividing with *i*. Start with `i=2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase `i` only if `i` does not divide n. 
Also, you can just check until the square root of `n`, since if `i` divides `n`, then `i <= sqrt(n)`.

Example:

```
import math

def prime_factors(n):

    i, factors = 2, []

    while n > 1 and i <= int(math.sqrt(n)):
        if n%i == 0:
            n/=i
            factors.append(i)
        else:
            i+=1

    if n > 1:
        factors.append(int(n))

    return factors


>>> prime_factors(64)
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
>>> prime_factors(28)
[2, 2, 7]
>>> prime_factors(31)
[31]
```

**Note**. You don't need to check if `i` is a prime number. `i` cannot be not prime, since if `i` were not prime, then there would exist a `j < i` that divides `i` with `j` being prime. Since `i` goes from `2` to `sqrt(n)`, it would have met before in the loop.

Comment: Could you explain the working of the code, how does it check where i is prime or not ?

Comment: Which line checks for the prime property of i ?

Comment: As in the previous comment, no need  to check if i is prime.