# Reducing execution time of factorization code

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program for prime factorization of a number and this is the code I came up with

```
    ss=0
    i=2
    y=n
    q=""
    while(i<=int((y)**(1/2))):
    #checking for prime
        t=0
        for j in range(2,int(i//2)):
            if(i==2):
                continue
            if(i%j==0):
                t=t+1   
        if(t>0):
            i=i+1
            continue
        else:
            if(n==0):
                break
            else:
                if(n%i==0):
                    n=int(n/i)
                    ss=ss+1
                    continue
                elif(n%i!=0 and ss>0):
                    if(ss==1):
                        q=q+"("+str(i)+")"
                    else:
                        q=q+"("+str(i)+"**"+str(ss)+")"
                    ss=0
                    i=i+1
                    continue
                else:
                    i=i+1
                    continue
    return q
```

The code runs perfectly fine for a certain range of numbers but shows the time out error on huge numbers.

Is there any way to improve efficiency of such programs as I have tried it much myself

Code working -

1. It checks whether the number in the outer loop is a prime or not
2. If it is a prime, then it proceeds to check whether division of the number with n would yield a remainder of 0 or not, if it does, divide it.
3. Increment ss which is the number of times the prime number would be used in the whole factorisation. Check again with the same number without incrementing i.
4. If it cannot divide and ss (number of times i could divide) is more than 0 then we add it to the output string

The output is of the form (2 * * 3)(3 * * 2) and so on, in this form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prime factorization of a big number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59961109/prime-factorization-of-a-big-number)

Comment: Yes, I've modified it according to the changes suggested and it works

Answer (score 0):

Well prime factorisation is a hard and CPU-intensive problem so Python (being a pretty slow language) is not a very good language for it. Aside from that and assuming you want to keep using python

1. you could use a better factorisation algorithm e.g. a sieve or (if the numbers you're trying to factor have specific known properties and one of them is suitable) a special-purpose factorisation algorithm
2. you could use an ad-hoc JIT like numba as your operations don't depend on python semantics